# Convert all anchor text that matches the format dd/mm/yyyy to mm/yyyy

Tags: jquery, regex, date, string-formatting

I have a table that is displaying information from out database. Because of the way our database has been setup, the date must be saved in formation dd/mm/yyyy however our client wishes for certain dates to be displayed in the formation mm/yyyy only. We cannot change the PL/SQL that generates the table nor can we change the database structure / expected format as the database is part of an overall product offering. I therefore need to loop through all anchor elements on my page, check whether the text value matches the format dd/mm/yyyy and if so run a substring to remove the first 3 characters regardless of what they are to leave just mm/yyyy.

So far I have tried the following code:

```
    $('table.work_section tr td a').each(function(){
        var regEx = new RegExp("^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$");
            if($(this).text().match(regEx) != null){
               var newText = $(this).substring(3);
               $(this).text(newText);
         }  
    })
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to be working. Does anyone have any ideas why?
My full code can be found in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehbSQ/23/

I also need an example of a regular expression for the date format:
01-OCT-2007

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I hate regular expressions.

Comment: You keep on changing your original `code`. I think this is not good idea.

Comment: Changing the original code to reflect changes in the sitution is the purpose of stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probmes with the code is:

- When you are using a string to construct a regular expression object, you need to escape all the backslashes in the string.
- You are using the undefined variable `$this` instead of `$(this)`.
- You are using `RegExp` when you try to use the variable `regEx`.
- You have an extra `var` in front of the last assignment.

Also:

- That regular expression is intended to validate a date, but you should use a much simpler expression as you only want to recognose a date.
- You can use the `test` method to find out if the regular expression matches, instead of making the full match and evaluating the result.
- Create the regular expression object outside the loop.

So:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^\\d+/\\d+/\\d+$");
$('table.work_section tr td a').each(function(){
  if(regEx.test($(this).text())){
    var newText = $(this).text().substring(3);
    $(this).text(newText);
  }  
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ehbSQ/31/

Comment: I already identified most of the problems with the code you pointed out. Maybe you didn't see the latest version of the fiddle but thanks for the solution. It works.

Comment: @jezzipin: I was busy solving the problem rather than repeatedly updating the question page... ;)

Comment: Just a quick addon, how would I change the regex to identify the date if it was in the format: 01-OCT-2007

Comment: @jezzipin: You could use something like `"\\d+-[A-Z]{3}-\\d+"` or `"\\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\\d{4}"` depending on how specific you think that you need to be.

Comment: Did you mean this instead: \d+-[A-Z]{3}-\d+

Comment: @jezzipin: I specifically wrote the strings for creating the regular expression objects, with escaped backslashes. It works fine when I test it: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/ehbSQ/33/

Answer (score 1):

That's an awfully long regex. Can you simply use this regex:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$");
```

**Your full code:**

```
$('table.work_section tr td a').each(function(){
    var regEx = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
    if( regEx.test( $(this).text() ) ) {
       var newText = $(this).text().substring(3);
       $(this).text(newText);
    }  
})
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehbSQ/32/)

Comment: Thanks for the new regEx. Like I say, I hate regEx so just stole that from somewhere online. I've added yours in now but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your Regex would match anything with the format of a date, for example 99/45/5245 which is not an acceptable date, unless there is some huge calendar change in the future :)

Comment: That's fine. Our dates are handled by the datebase anyway to ensure they are in the correct format. All I am looking to change is something that appears like a date or in the format dd/mm/yyyy as that is all that could possibly appear.

Comment: @Theox: Of course it will match that imaginary date of yours but look at the intent of the code. OP just detects date **already fetched from database, NOT from any user input** and it just stripts out date part from it.

Comment: @jezzipin: Can you just dump `$this.text()` using `console.log($this.text());` to see what value are you getting.

Comment: Nothing is returned by a console.log($this.text());

Comment: Your RegEx https://www.debuggex.com/r/je1x7ECL8hQuGSKL and @anubhava RegEx https://www.debuggex.com/r/fkfc42Mo277Va0ml

Comment: What about it? I've improved my original code to ensure that the this selector is working

Comment: @jezzipin: Nothing will be returned by `console.log($this.text());` It writes this value on console (see it from Firebug). If you just replace that by `akert($this.text());` to see date text value on screen.

Comment: I've fixed that now. It is selecting my values correctly but it doesn't seem to filtering the regex correctly.

Comment: @jezzipin: See full code in my updated answer and working JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ehbSQ/32/

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems with your code.

1. Your selecter `table.work_section > tr > td > a` is not selecting elements properly (as I understood)
2. Your regex is not escaped properly in string.
3. Your code is wrong `$this.text()` use this '$(this).text()' and instead of `var $this.text(newText);` use `$(this).text(newText);`

For details see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ekYqn/3/). Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekYqn/3/)